# Reading xml file from specific line

Tags: c#, xml

this is my situation:

```
public static string ReadFromLine(int lineNumber, params string[] searchedAttribute)
{
    //XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlFilePath);
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.LineNumberOffset = lineNumber;
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(xmlFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs, settings);

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == searchedAttribute[0] || reader.Name == searchedAttribute[1])
        {
            if(reader.Name == searchedAttribute[0])
                reader.MoveToAttribute(searchedAttribute[0]);
            else
                reader.MoveToAttribute(searchedAttribute[1]);

            string currentAttributeValue = reader.ReadElementString();
            return currentAttributeValue;
        }
    }
    return "notFound";
}
```

In the method I want to read a xml file from line that is passed in the variable "linenumber".

Unfortunately, despite using my settings according to documentation, my **reader starts at line 1** every time.

Appreciate any ideas how to solve it or another solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, despite using my settings according to documentation...

There must be some misunderstanding here. An `XmlReader` always starts from the current position of the passed `Stream`, `TextReader`, etc.

All what `LineNumberOffset` does is just an adjustment of the *reported* line number (if there is any error during the processing, for example).

A possible (but not quite recommended) solution can be if you embed your `FileStream` into a `StreamReader`, read `lineNumber` of lines, and then create an `XmlReader` passing the `StreamReader` at the current position to the `XmlReader.Create(TextReader,XmlReaderSettings)` overload:

```cs
using var stream = File.OpenRead(xmlFilePath);

// skipping lineNumber of lines
var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
for (int i = 0; i < lineNumber; i++)
    streamReader.ReadLine();

XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sreamReader, settings);
```

But in fact a more preferable (and formatting-proof) solution would be to read the whole XML into an`XDocument` and then navigate in the content by [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/basic-queries-linq-to-xml).

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure how to write it, could you send a chunk of code, please?

Comment: When the StreamReader read "lineNumber" lines, how do I pass it to XmlReader that it will start from the line, where StreamReader ended?